# Error with Redux Toolkit createSlice function in React Native (EXPO)

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

I'm encountering an issue in my Expo project where I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: 0, _toolkit.createSlice is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
    at ContextNavigator (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:153417:24)
    at ExpoRoot (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:153388:30)
    at App
    at withDevTools(App) (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:132684:27)
    at ErrorToastContainer (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:132585:24)
    at ErrorOverlay
    at RCTView
    at View (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:40235:43)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:40235:43)
    at AppContainer (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:40075:36)
    at main(RootComponent) (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.reportAdd.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:121767:28)
```

Details:

Environment: Expo ( SDK 49 )
Error Message: TypeError: 0, _toolkit.createSlice is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes.

Redux packages installed
"react-redux": "^9.0.4",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",

File causing the error

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "../store";

type initialStateTypes = {
  notificationToken: string;
  hasCreatedAccount: boolean;
  currentPhoneNumber?: string;
};


const initialState: initialStateTypes = {
  notificationToken: "",
  hasCreatedAccount: false,
  currentPhoneNumber: "",
};

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState,
  reducers: {

    setNotificationToken: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.notificationToken = action.payload;
    },

    setHasCreatedAccount: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.hasCreatedAccount = action.payload;
    },

    setCurrentPhoneNumber: (state, action) => {
      state.currentPhoneNumber = action.payload;
    },

    clear() {
      // Note that this should be left intentionally empty.
      // Clearing redux state and localForage happens in rootReducer.ts.
    },
  },
});

// Extract the action creators object and the reducer.
const { actions, reducer } = appSlice;

// Extract and export each action creator by name.
export const {
  setNotificationToken,
  setHasCreatedAccount,
  setCurrentPhoneNumber,
  clear,
} = actions;


export const selectNotificationToken = (state: RootState) =>
  state.app.notificationToken;
  
export const selectHasCreatedAccount = (state: RootState) =>
  state.app.hasCreatedAccount;


  // Export the reducer, either as a default.
export default reducer;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Been looking for a week and still nothing. Created a project to recreate the issue but it works perfectly on the latter.

Answer (score 1):

- After a week of research and analysis, I finally found the solution. I hope it saves someone's time. The **error results from** a metro bundler problem handling the `.cjs` extension common to dependencies. Unfortunately, `.cjs` isn't the only one, there's `.mjs` etc.
- In my case the `.cjs` was at play. The **solution** was to have my `metro.config.js` file looking as follows:

```js
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

// What I had initially, was affecting `getReactNativePersistence`-import {
// initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth"; as well
// config.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

//Fixes
// config.resolver.sourceExts.push("cjs");

// config.resolver.sourceExts = process.env.RN_SRC_EXT
//   ? [
//       ...process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(",").concat(config.resolver.sourceExts),
//       "cjs",
//     ] // <-- cjs added here
//   : [...config.resolver.sourceExts, "cjs"]; // <-- cjs added here

config.resolver.sourceExts.push("js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "cjs");

module.exports = config;
```

- Play around with the **commented segments under the fixes comment** and see what works for you.
- If the above doesn't work, there are a couple of suggested solutions:

  - [Link 1](https://github.com/thysultan/stylis/issues/233)
  - [Link 2](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/535)

### All the best